# Actionscript 3.0 - MouseEvents not working

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, stage

I'm trying to code a sort of strategy game through FlashDevelop and I'm getting problems when trying to use Events (particularly MouseEvents). It's not so much that the events are returning errors, it's just that they don't do anything, not even getting a trace.

I'm trying to make the hexagons `HexObject` image invisible when clicked on (just a simple test to see if the MouseEvent is actually working).

This is my code:

Main.as

```
package {
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Dean Sinclair
     */

    public class Main extends Sprite {

        public var gameInitialised:Boolean = false;
        public var MIN_X:int = 0;
        public var MAX_X:int = stage.stageWidth;
        public var MIN_Y:int = 0;
        public var MAX_Y:int = stage.stageHeight - 100;

        public var GameGrid:HexGrid = new HexGrid(MIN_X, MAX_X, MIN_Y, MAX_Y);
        public var blackBG:Shape = new Shape();

        public function Main():void {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
            // entry point
        }

        private function update(event:Event):void {
            if (gameInitialised == false) {
                GameGrid.initialiseGrid();
                initialiseBackground();
                gameInitialised = true;
            }

            updateGraphics();
        }

        public function drawGrid():void {
            for (var x:int = 0; x < GameGrid.TOTAL_X; x++) {
                for (var y:int = GameGrid.yArray[x][0]; y < GameGrid.yArray[x][1]; y++) {
                    if (x != GameGrid.nox || y != GameGrid.noy) {
                        GameGrid.Grid[x][y].update();
                        this.stage.addChild(GameGrid.Grid[x][y].image);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public function updateGraphics():void {
            this.stage.addChild(blackBG);
            drawGrid();
        }

        public function initialiseBackground():void {
            blackBG.graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 1);
            blackBG.graphics.lineStyle(10, 0xffffff, 1);
            blackBG.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, stage.stageWidth-1, stage.stageHeight-1);
            blackBG.graphics.endFill();
        }

    }

}
```

HexGrid.as

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Dean Sinclair
     */
    public class HexGrid extends Sprite {

        public static var HEX_RADIUS:int = 0;
        public static var HEX_DIAMETER:int = 0;
        public static var GRID_WIDTH:int = 0;
        public static var GRID_HEIGHT:int = 0;
        public var TOTAL_X:int = 0;

        public var MIN_X:int = 0;
        public var MAX_X:int = 0;
        public var MIN_Y:int = 0;
        public var MAX_Y:int = 0;

        public var Grid:Array;
        public var yArray:Array;

        public function HexGrid(min_x:int, max_x:int, min_y:int, max_y:int) {
            super();
            MIN_X = min_x;
            MAX_X = max_x;
            MIN_Y = min_y;
            MAX_Y = max_y;
        }

        public function initialiseGrid():void {
            setGridDetails();
            setLineLengths();
            setGridPositions();
        }

        public function setGridDetails():void {
            HEX_RADIUS = 25;
            HEX_DIAMETER = 2 * HEX_RADIUS;
            GRID_WIDTH = (((MAX_X - MIN_X) / HEX_DIAMETER) - 1);
            GRID_HEIGHT = ((((MAX_Y - 100) - MIN_Y) / (HEX_DIAMETER - (HEX_DIAMETER / 3))) - 3);
            TOTAL_X = GRID_WIDTH + Math.floor((GRID_HEIGHT - 1) / 2);
        }

        private function setLineLengths():void {
            yArray = new Array(TOTAL_X);
            for (var a:int = 0; a < TOTAL_X; a++) {
                yArray[a] = new Array(2);
            }
            for (var x:int = 0; x < TOTAL_X; x++) {
                if (x < GRID_WIDTH) {
                    yArray[x][0] = 0;
                }else {
                    yArray[x][0] = (x - GRID_WIDTH + 1) * 2;
                }
                yArray[x][1] = 1 + (2 * x);
                if (yArray[x][1] > GRID_HEIGHT) {
                    yArray[x][1] = GRID_HEIGHT;
                }
                trace("Line", x, "   starts at", yArray[x][0], "   ends at", yArray[x][1]);
            }
        }

        public var nox:int = 5;
        public var noy:int = 3;

        private function setGridPositions():void {
            var hexState:int = 4;

            Grid = new Array(TOTAL_X);
            for (var x:int = 0; x < TOTAL_X; x++) {
                Grid[x] = new Array(yArray[x][1]);
                for (var y:int = yArray[x][0]; y < yArray[x][1]; y++) {
                    if(nox!=4 || noy!=6){
                        Grid[x][y] = new HexObject(HEX_DIAMETER + (HEX_DIAMETER * x) - (HEX_RADIUS * y), HEX_DIAMETER + (HEX_DIAMETER * y) - ((HEX_DIAMETER / 3) * y), HEX_RADIUS, 2);
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HexObject.as

```
package {
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Dean Sinclair
     */
    public class HexObject extends Sprite {
        [Embed(source = "../images/hexagons/hex_darkRed.png")]
        private var DarkRedHex:Class;
        [Embed(source = "../images/hexagons/hex_lightBlue.png")]
        private var LightBlueHex:Class;
        [Embed(source = "../images/hexagons/hex_midGreen.png")]
        private var MidGreenHex:Class;

        public var image:Bitmap = new LightBlueHex();
        protected var state:int = 0;
        private var radius:int = 0;

        public function HexObject(xPos:int, yPos:int, hexRadius:int, hexState:int) {
            super();
            x = xPos;
            y = yPos;
            state = hexState;
            radius = hexRadius;
            checkState();
            initialiseGraphics();
        }

        private function checkState():void {
            switch(state) {
                case 1:     // plains
                    image = new MidGreenHex();
                    break;
                case 2:     // hills
                    break;
                case 3:     // rock
                    image = new DarkRedHex();
                    break;
                case 4:     // water
                    image = new LightBlueHex();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        private function initialiseGraphics():void {
            image.visible = true;
            image.width = radius * 2;
            image.height = radius * 2;
            image.x = x - radius;
            image.y = y - radius;
        }

        private function onMouseClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
            image.visible = false;
            trace("image.visible =", image.visible);
        }

        public function update():void {
            image.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMouseClick);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried countless methods to get the events working, but none have had any success. Any sort of solution to this would be a lifesaver as I've been toiling over this for hours, thanks!

Comment: You have a lot of initialization code inside functions that get called every frame, I'd start by extracting that

Comment: I've re-designed the code so that the initialised code isn't called every frame, and it's tidier, but it still doesn't show the trace. It's as if the objects haven't even been added to the stage, despite them showing correctly.

Comment: I would recommend editing your post to show the updated code. But anyway, your problem is that image is a `Bitmap` which won;t dispatch mouseevents, put it in a container `Sprite`

Comment: Updated the post now. Thanks, that sheds a lot of light on my problem. How exactly would I put it in a Sprite container though?

Comment: create imageContainer Sprite inside HexObject, then imageContainer.addChild(image). Now instead of referring to obj.image in other classes, change it to imageContainer. Although I would refactor your code to simply add the image as a child of HexObject (which is a Sprite) then remove all uses of .image from other classes & just deal with the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was fixed by `VBCPP`, I was using the class `Bitmap` which cannot dispatch MouseEvents. The solution was to take `image` from `HexObject` and put it inside an container of type `Sprite`, with the logical one being the object it was in. I just had to add the following code inside `HexObject.as`:

```
this.addChild(image);
```

and then just refer to the Object in future as opposed to `image`.